# Is it possible to pass child class object in a map with base class definition?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to create a extensive database for a company. I have made different classes for every level of employee. But i don't understand how do i push different type objects in a single map.

As far as i have tried it just gets pushed, shows no compilation error as for now atleast.

```
class EmployeeClass
{}

class CEOClass: public EmployeeClass
{}

class ManagerClass:public EmployeeClass
{}

class EngineerClass: public EmployeeClass
{}

int main()
{
    EngineerClass engineerClassObject;
    std::map<std::string employeeName, EmployeeClass> employeeMap;

    employeeMap.insert({employeeName, enginerrClassObject});
}
```

I want to understand if i can do this. If not what is the best way of doing this without adding extra maps. If yes how is possible and how does it work?

Comment: [Object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). That's not how you do *polymorphism*. You have to use pointers.

Comment: could you please give me some example

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Polymorphism kicks in when you have reference/pointer to the base object.

```
EmployeeClass *engineerClassObject = new EngineerClass();
std::map<std::string, EmployeeClass*> employeeMap;

employeeMap.insert({employeeName, engineerClassObject});
```

and then

```
employeeMap["some_emp_name"]->some_virtual_function();
```

Comment: I would use a smart pointer instead for memory management, e.g. std::shared_ptr<EmployeeClass> pEngineer = std::make_shared<ManagerClass>();

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers or references.

Here an exsample with pointers and `std::pair`.

```
int main()
{
    EngineerClass engineerClassObject;
    std:string employeeName = "Peter";
    std::map<std::string employeeName, EmployeeClass*> employeeMap;

    employeeMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,EmployeeClass*>(employeeName, &enginerrClassObject));
}
```

Edit:

Exsample with a reference:

```
  int main()
    {
        EngineerClass engineerClassObject;
        std:string employeeName = "Peter";
        std::map<std::string employeeName, EmployeeClass&> employeeMap;

        employeeMap.insert(std::pair<std::string,EmployeeClass&>(employeeName, enginerrClassObject));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store pointers, and they better be smart ones. For example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<EmployeeClass>> employeeMap;
employeeMap.insert({"Engineer", std::make_unique<EngineerClass>()});
```

or

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<EmployeeClass>> employeeMap;
auto engineer = std::make_unique<EngineerClass>()
employeeMap.insert({"Engineer", std::move(engineer)});
```